# Finding primitive element of an extension

Tags: polynomials, extension-field, minimal-polynomials, splitting-field

First: I know that there is some questions on MSE that cover this problem, but I didn't find any answer that solves the problem straightforward by the method of the primitive element theorem.

I want to find a primitive element for the extension $K | \Bbb{Q}$, where $K$ is the splitting field of $f(X)=X^4-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}.$

I know that $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i\sqrt[4]{2})=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$. If $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{2}$ and $\beta=i$, I know that exists an primitive element $\gamma=\alpha+c\beta$, $c\in \Bbb{Q}$ such that $K=\Bbb{Q}(\gamma),$ so I just need to find such $c$. My question is to how  to it.

I know that $[K,\Bbb{Q}]=8$, so I tried to find $c\in\Bbb{Q}$ such that $\gamma\in K$ and $\deg (p_{\gamma})=8$, where $p_{\gamma}$ si the minimal polynomial of $\gamma$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. If I do it, so I can take $\gamma$ as primitive element.

However, I coldn't and I don't know if there is some straightforward method to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: $c=1$ works. Indeed, the minimal polynomial of $\gamma=\alpha+\beta$ is $x^8 + 4 x^6 + 2 x^4 + 28 x^2 + 1$ and so $K=\mathbb Q(\gamma)$. Thanks to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimal+polynomial+2%5E%281%2F4%29%2Bi).

Comment: How could I get this minimal polynomial? I mean, seeing now its easy to now that this is the minimal polynomial, but how could I build it?

Comment: One way is to express the $1,\gamma,\gamma^2,\dots,\gamma^7$ in a basis of $K$ and show that they are linearly independent. This amounts to matrix row reduction.